# Best practice for submitting a website to google search engine

Tags: seo, google-search

I am about to manually submit a website url to the [google search console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url) to be indexed. I will like to know if there will be a major difference between adding the **www** along with my url (**http://www.example.com**) as apposed to just submitting the domain name (**http://example.com**).

I have read the google guidelines and watched a few of their search-console videos but they didn't mention anything about the importance of the **www**.

Do i gain or loose anything from including or excluding the **www** from my URL when submitting it to the google search console for indexing?

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best Regards.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in submitting www vs non-www version. The only thing you should be care about is that only one version is actual. You should choose the domain name for your website and put a 301 Moved Permanently redirect at other name.

It is very important to have only one copy of your content. Duplicated content is penalized by Google and if you have your website open at domain.com and www.domain.com then this instantly creates duplicated content of all pages of your website.

The second thing you should do before submitting your website is to create a sitemap. From my experience when a site has a sitemap google index it much faster.

You should also review all titles, meta descriptions and other SEO issues. I would recommend to check your whole website for SEO issues with some SEO crawler. Try screaming frog if you want to test from your local computer or use online service like https://seocharger.com to check online. You can even set up SEO monitoring there.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice.
Seeing that using both www and just the domain name could create duplicates i will try and stick to only using the domain name WITH the www prefix. I will go check out those SEO crawlers now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To your question. I personally think the only distinct difference I can think of is that a potential consumer that would visit your website will be more used to seeing www. instead of just purely http://domain.com 
I would recommend you opt for http://www.domain.com, besides that there will not be any difference in SEO Value.

Comment: the reason behind is that people tend to like things that they see behaving 'normally' - this is a pyschological component to ponder and act upon